# SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON is not setting ARITHABORT value ON. Is the documentation correct?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2017.

It seems that `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON` is not setting `ARITHABORT` value ON as the documentation suggests or am I misunderstanding?

e.g. commands

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

SET ARITHABORT OFF

SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

says:

> Setting ANSI_WARNINGS to ON implicitly sets ARITHABORT to ON when the database compatibility level is set to 90 or higher. If the database compatibility level is set to 80 or earlier, the ARITHABORT option must be explicitly set to ON.

What does this mean?

Does this mean (?)

So even if the `ARITHABORT` setting value is OFF and displaying as OFF and the ANSI_WARNINGS setting is ON then the `ARITHABORT` setting value is actually ON (even though display and queried values show OFF) for database compatibility level 90 or higher ..

or should I expect to be able to see `ARITHABORT` set to ON after `SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON`?

Am using SQL to query the settings along these lines

```
SELECT @@OPTIONS AS [user_options],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 2 = 2 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [implicit_transactions],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 4 = 4 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [cursor_close_on_commit],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 8 = 8 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_warnings],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 16 = 16 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_padding],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 32 = 32 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_nulls],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 64 = 64 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [arithabort],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 256 = 256 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [quoted_identifier],
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 1024 = 1024 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_null_dflt_on],
       -- all above options combined
       CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 1342 = 1342 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS [ansi_defaults]
```

and also

```
select db_name(database_id), ansi_warnings, arithabort, * 
from sys.dm_Exec_sessions
```

Comment: The bottom line is that `ARITHABORT ON` is set automatically when you use a  modern client driver and SQL Server version SQL 2012 or later, which does not support database compatibility levels lower than 90. The only way to turn it off is with an explict `ARITHABORT OFF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I considered the output from this test script which confirms that when ANSI_WARNINGS setting is ON then the ARITHABORT setting value has no impact. i.e. acts as if ARITHABORT is ON even if set OFF .. when ANSI_WARNINGS is set ON ..

```
PRINT '*** SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON'; 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

-- SET ARITHABORT  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
-- Create tables t1 and t2 and insert data values.  
CREATE TABLE t1 (  
   a TINYINT,   
   b TINYINT  
);  
CREATE TABLE t2 (  
   a TINYINT  
);  
GO  
INSERT INTO t1   
VALUES (1, 0);  
INSERT INTO t1   
VALUES (255, 1);  
GO  

PRINT '*** SET ARITHABORT ON';  
GO  
-- SET ARITHABORT ON and testing.  
SET ARITHABORT ON;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT';  
GO  
SELECT a / b AS ab   
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a / b AS ab    
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Testing tinyint overflow';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a + b AS ab   
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Resulting data - should be no data';  
GO  
SELECT *   
FROM t2;  
GO  

-- Truncate table t2.  
TRUNCATE TABLE t2;  
GO  

-- SET ARITHABORT OFF and testing.  
PRINT '*** SET ARITHABORT OFF';  
GO  
SET ARITHABORT OFF;  
GO  

-- This works properly.  
PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT';  
GO  
SELECT a / b AS ab    
FROM t1;  
GO  

-- This works as if SET ARITHABORT was ON.  
PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a / b AS ab    
FROM t1;  
GO  
PRINT '*** Testing tinyint overflow';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a + b AS ab   
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Resulting data - should be 0 rows';  
GO  
SELECT *   
FROM t2;  
GO  

-- Drop tables t1 and t2.  
DROP TABLE t1;  
DROP TABLE t2;  
GO  

PRINT '*** ############################################################################################################################'; 
PRINT '*** ############################################################################################################################'; 
PRINT '*** SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF'; 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

-- SET ARITHABORT  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
-- Create tables t1 and t2 and insert data values.  
CREATE TABLE t1 (  
   a TINYINT,   
   b TINYINT  
);  
CREATE TABLE t2 (  
   a TINYINT  
);  
GO  
INSERT INTO t1   
VALUES (1, 0);  
INSERT INTO t1   
VALUES (255, 1);  
GO  

PRINT '*** SET ARITHABORT ON';  
GO  
-- SET ARITHABORT ON and testing.  
SET ARITHABORT ON;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT';  
GO  
SELECT a / b AS ab   
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a / b AS ab    
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Testing tinyint overflow';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a + b AS ab   
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Resulting data - should be no data';  
GO  
SELECT *   
FROM t2;  
GO  

-- Truncate table t2.  
TRUNCATE TABLE t2;  
GO  

-- SET ARITHABORT OFF and testing.  
PRINT '*** SET ARITHABORT OFF';  
GO  
SET ARITHABORT OFF;  
GO  

-- This works properly.  
PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT';  
GO  
SELECT a / b AS ab    
FROM t1;  
GO  

-- This works as if SET ARITHABORT was ON.  
PRINT '*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a / b AS ab    
FROM t1;  
GO  
PRINT '*** Testing tinyint overflow';  
GO  
INSERT INTO t2  
SELECT a + b AS ab   
FROM t1;  
GO  

PRINT '*** Resulting data - should be 0 rows';  
GO  
SELECT *   
FROM t2;  
GO  

-- Drop tables t1 and t2.  
DROP TABLE t1;  
DROP TABLE t2;  
GO  


PRINT '*** ############################################################################################################################';
```

I get this result:

```
*** SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)
*** SET ARITHABORT ON
*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Divide by zero error encountered.
*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Divide by zero error encountered.
The statement has been terminated.
*** Testing tinyint overflow
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 42
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type tinyint.
The statement has been terminated.
*** Resulting data - should be no data

(0 rows affected)
*** SET ARITHABORT OFF
*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 66
Divide by zero error encountered.
*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
Divide by zero error encountered.
The statement has been terminated.
*** Testing tinyint overflow
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 79
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type tinyint.
The statement has been terminated.
*** Resulting data - should be 0 rows

(0 rows affected)
*** ############################################################################################################################
*** ############################################################################################################################
*** SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)
*** SET ARITHABORT ON
*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 125
Divide by zero error encountered.
*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 131
Divide by zero error encountered.
*** Testing tinyint overflow
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 138
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type tinyint.
*** Resulting data - should be no data

(0 rows affected)
*** SET ARITHABORT OFF
*** Testing divide by zero during SELECT
Division by zero occurred.

(2 rows affected)
*** Testing divide by zero during INSERT
Division by zero occurred.

(2 rows affected)
*** Testing tinyint overflow
Arithmetic overflow occurred.

(2 rows affected)
*** Resulting data - should be 0 rows

(4 rows affected)
*** ############################################################################################################################
```

Comment: This documentation sentence changed (I supplied an edit suggestion to Microsoft) and now reads as per this:   "When ANSI_WARNINGS has a value of ON and the database compatibility level is set to 90 or higher then ARITHABORT is implicitly ON regardless of it's value setting."      Hopefully this is clear and correct ..